# Printing a * pattern

Tags: java

So I have to print the following pattern by accepting a value of n 
     Input : 7
     Output has to be this :

```
    *
    **
    ***
    ****
    *****
    ******
    *******
    ******
    *****
    ****
    ***
    **
    *
```

code:

```
public static void printPattern(int n)
{
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)   
    {
        for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)   
        {
            System.out.println("*");
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }   
    for (int a = n-1; a >= 1; a--)
    {
        for (int b = 1; b <= a; b++)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
}
```

But for some reason it prints this pattern(say n=8):

```
*


*
*
*
*
*


*
*
*
*
*
*


*
*
*
*
*
*
*


*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*


*******

******

*****

****

***

**

*
```

What is the mistake here?

Comment: You are using `System.out.println`, instead use `System.out.print` which will skip printing new line after each print.

Answer (score 2):

Use `System.out.print` instead of `System.out.println` in the first for loop, the latter one always appends a newline character at the end which is what you are trying to do manually.

And either do `System.out.print("\n");` OR `System.out.println("");` to add the newline after the inner loop iteration.

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.println` already adds a line break at the end, therefore `System.out.println("\n")` adds two line breaks.

The code can be condensed to a single double-for loop. The following routine accepts a single parameter which defines the maximum number of '*' on a single line:

```
/**
 * @param width
 *            the maximum width of the pattern.
 */
public static void print(int width) {
    for (int i = 1; i < 2 * width; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width - Math.abs(width - i); ++j)
            System.out.print("*");
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    print(4);
}
```

Output:

```
*
**
***
****
***
**
*
```

Answer (score 0):

first for loop should be like this,

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.print("*");

            }
            System.out.print("\n");

        }

System.out.println();
```

always move the cursor to a new line
in your code when we use `System.out.println("\n");` this will move cursor to 2 lines

Comment: Nope, don't do System.out.println("\n"); it will skip 2 lines

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
     for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
         System.out.print("*");
     }
     System.out.println();
}
for (int a = n - 1; a >= 1; a--) {
     for (int b = 1; b <= a; b++) {
         System.out.print("*");
     }
     System.out.println();
}
```

By changing `println` to `print` you won't go to another line after each `*` and remove the `\n` to not skip 2 lines because print**ln** it's already there